# Sorting data in JSON response for comparison

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to compare 2 full JSON responses - expected and actual for Pass/Fail status. My expected response in the excel sheet is not in the same sequence as I get after running API request as Actual Response, which causes 1 on 1 comparison to fail. To solve this issue, I need to sort the data in the Expected Response to match it to Actual Response format before comparison. Below is the Expected and Actual response for reference. Can anyone help with this?

Expected Response -

"Drivers": [
{
"ContactId": 501019,
"LicenseNumber": " ",
"LicenseState": "VA",
**"DriverNumber": 3,**
"DriverStatus": "Active",
"DriverTerminationDate": null,
"DriverUsed": false,
"PolicyDateTimeDriverAdd": "2016-07-26T11:45:05",
"PolicyDateTimeMax": "2016-07-26T21:34:10"
},
{
"ContactId": 501018,
"LicenseNumber": " ",
"LicenseState": "VA",
**"DriverNumber": 2,**
"DriverStatus": "Active",
"DriverTerminationDate": null,
"DriverUsed": true,
"PolicyDateTimeDriverAdd": "2016-07-26T11:45:05",
"PolicyDateTimeMax": "2016-07-26T21:34:10"
},
{
"ContactId": 501017,
"LicenseNumber": " ",
"LicenseState": "VA",
**"DriverNumber": 1,**
"DriverStatus": "Active",
"DriverTerminationDate": null,
"DriverUsed": true,
"PolicyDateTimeDriverAdd": "2016-07-26T11:45:05",
"PolicyDateTimeMax": "2016-07-26T21:34:10"
}
]

Actual Response -

"Drivers": [
{
"ContactId": 501017,
"LicenseNumber": " ",
"LicenseState": "VA",
**"DriverNumber": 1,**
"DriverStatus": "Active",
"DriverTerminationDate": null,
"DriverUsed": true,
"PolicyDateTimeDriverAdd": "2016-07-26T11:45:05",
"PolicyDateTimeMax": "2016-07-26T21:34:10"
},
{
"ContactId": 501018,
"LicenseNumber": " ",
"LicenseState": "VA",
**"DriverNumber": 2,**
"DriverStatus": "Active",
"DriverTerminationDate": null,
"DriverUsed": true,
"PolicyDateTimeDriverAdd": "2016-07-26T11:45:05",
"PolicyDateTimeMax": "2016-07-26T21:34:10"
},
{
"ContactId": 501019,
"LicenseNumber": " ",
"LicenseState": "VA",
**"DriverNumber": 3,**
"DriverStatus": "Active",
"DriverTerminationDate": null,
"DriverUsed": false,
"PolicyDateTimeDriverAdd": "2016-07-26T11:45:05",
"PolicyDateTimeMax": "2016-07-26T21:34:10"
},
{
"ContactId": 501021,
"LicenseNumber": " ",
"LicenseState": "VA",
"DriverNumber": 4,
"DriverStatus": "Active",
"DriverTerminationDate": null,
"DriverUsed": false,
"PolicyDateTimeDriverAdd": "2016-07-26T11:45:05",
"PolicyDateTimeMax": "2016-07-26T21:34:10"
}
]

I have highlighted the field DriverNumber in Expected Response that I would like to sort the data before comparison in ascending order 1,2,3

Comment: What have you tried?  How far did you get?  What errors did you see?

Comment: Below is the code I tried for Sorting data in Expected Response by DriverNumber 1,2,3 -

Comment: //Sorting Expected Response by DriverNumber 1,2,3
def expectedMap = [ : ];
expectedMap = convertJsontoMap(expected)
log.info(expectedMap)
def ExpectedMap = expectedMap.sort({it1, it2 -> it1.value <=> it1.value})        
log.info("ExpectedMap is " +ExpectedMap) 
                                                                                                      
def result = ExpectedMap.findAll{it.key == "Drivers[0].DriverNumber"}
log.info(result)

Comment: But above SORT is not returning response by DriverNumber 1,2,3